# How can I implement Advanced Search using HTML?

Tags: html, forms

**I have been trying to implement a form that goes to a search of some word in advanced search using Google search, a problem is during I want to implement the code it redirects to the Google search page.**

- *this what I tried to write it*

> Thank you"

```
<form action="https://google.com/search">
    <h2>Find Pages with</h2>
    <div class="input-group row">
        <label class="lb" for="fword">all these words:</label>
        <div class="input-lb">
            <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="af-w"><br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group row">
        <label class="lb" for="phword">this exact word or phrase:</label>
        <div class="input-lb">
            <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="ew-p"><br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group row">
        <label class="lb" for="aword">any of these words:</label>
        <div class="input-lb">
            <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="a-w"><br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group row">
        <label class="lb" for="nword">none of these words:</label>
        <div class="input-lb">
            <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="n-w"><br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnA" class="btn" value="Advanced Search" aria-label="Advanced Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using outdated `name` values inside your form, which is causing your form to improperly submit to Google advanced search. Make sure to replace each of the values with the current ones listed below.

*all these words:* `as_q`

*this exact word or phrase:* `as_epq`

*any of these words:* `as_oq`

*none of these words:* `as_eq`

With the values replaced with the new ones, your form should look like this:

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
  <h2>Find Pages with</h2>
  <div class="input-group row">
    <label class="lb" for="fword">all these words:</label>
    <div class="input-lb">
      <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="as_q"><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group row">
    <label class="lb" for="phword">this exact word or phrase:</label>
    <div class="input-lb">
      <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="as_epq"><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group row">
    <label class="lb" for="aword">any of these words:</label>
    <div class="input-lb">
      <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="as_oq"><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group row">
    <label class="lb" for="nword">none of these words:</label>
    <div class="input-lb">
      <input type="text" class="from-ad" name="as_eq"><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="btnA" class="btn" value="Advanced Search" aria-label="Advanced Search">
  </div>
</form>
```